# How to read bytes into arrays by specifying offset and byte length using the DataInputStream class?

Tags: java, io, binaryfiles

I declare and allocate some byte arrays. I want to initialize these arrays with the read(byte array, offset, byte length) method. The first read method statement seems to read the first 32 bytes correctly into the array. However, the second read method does not and throws an indexOutOfBounds exception.

Specification for the offset values:

```
offset 0, length 32 bytes - contains some text
offset 32, length 2 bytes - contains something else
etc
```

Here is the code:

```
File file = new File("somebinaryfile.dat");
DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));

byte[] array1 = new byte[32];   // first array 
byte[] array2 = new byte[2];    // second array

in.read(array1, 0, 32);
in.read(array2, 32, 2);

in.close();
```

I'm working under the assumption(probably incorrectly) that the read position will automatically increase during each new .read() method statement. Yet if I allocate 34 elements to array2 instead of just 2 elements, then no exception is thrown. Therefore, it appears that the first 34 bytes are being read into array2 instead of just the last 2 bytes even though I'm specifying offset and byte length...

I realize the RandomAccessFile class has a nifty .seek(n) method. However, I'm pretty stubborn and want to stick with DataInputStream.

Any advice on correct usage in order to initialize the two arrays with data obtained using the specified offset and byte length?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The offset argument of `read(byte[] arr, int offset, int length)` is the offset of the `arr`. Not the offset of the stream.

Thus

```
in.read(array2, 32, 2);
```

means that you want to read 2 bytes from the in `InputStream` into `array2` at offset 32, but array2 has only a length of 2 bytes. That causes the `IndexOutOfBounds`.

Use

```
in.read(array2, 0, 2);
```

to fill `array2` with the next 2 bytes from the `InputStream`.